# By.className("classname") and By.cssSelector("[class = 'classname']") returns different number of elements in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dom

I am learning Selenium and came across an issue where I see that By.cssSelector("[class = 'day']") and By.className("day") are returning different number of elements even though both are the same.

I see that when I use By.className("day"), the disabled dates in the calendar are also selected when ideally it should not as the class name for those disabled dates is "old day"  not "day".

driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companions");

driver.findElement(By.name("travel_date")).click();

List elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[class 
   'day']"));

List elements1 = driver.findElements(By.className("day"));

System.out.println(elements.size());

System.out.println(elements1.size());

Expected: 30 elements should be returned.
Actual:
With Css selector - I can see 30 but with Classname - I see 42.

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is in the following:

`By.className("cls")` returns elements which have that class, e.g.:

- `<span class="cls">`
- `<span class="cls other values here">`
- `<span class="any-combination cls of-classes">`

`By.cssSelector("[class='cls']")` returns elements who have `class` attribute exactly equal to expression in quotes, e.g.:

- `<span class="cls">`
- and nothing else

Note: just checked this on the site you've linked (after opening calendar), and it seems to be true:

- `$('.day').length` == 42
- `$('[class=day]').length` == 31

Comment: Thanks alx, seems like it is expected behavior as per selenium documentation.                   
By org.openqa.selenium.By.className(String className)

Find elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. If an element has multiple classes, then this will match against each of them. For example, if the value is "one two onone", then the class names "one" and "two" will match.